# Is there any reason to continue reading InputStream if number of read byte is 0?

Tags: java

Usually, when I deal with `InputStream`, and condition of stop reading is when the number of read byte is less than or equal to 0

For instance,

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

// Transfer bytes from in to out
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
    out.write(buf, 0, len);
}
```

However, when I look at the documentation of `InputStream`

[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D))

Only I notice that

> -1 if there is no more data because the end of the stream has been reached.

I was wondering, should I refactor my code to

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

// Transfer bytes from in to out
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
    if (len > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
}
```

Will there be any edge case checking for `while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0)` is going to cause any unwanted bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `read` is specified to block until data is available, the only way that it returns `0` is if the buffer you input into is is of length 0 (which would be a pretty useless buffer).

See [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D)):

> This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown.

and

> If the length of b is zero, then no bytes are read and 0 is returned; otherwise, there is an attempt to read at least one byte.

So the four possible cases are:

1. `b` is a `byte[]` of length 0, so 0 is returned
2. input data is available: non-zero bytes will be read into `b` and that number returned.
3. end of file is detected: -1 will be returned
4. an exception thrown: no value is returned, when a method returns abnormally with an exception.

Comment: If that is that case, checking for != -1 or > 0 will both fine?

Comment: Yes, but I'd rather check for `-1` because it's explicitly stated in the JavaDoc and requires less deep understanding to grok.